# App review status(always "waiting for upload") not change

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, appstore-approval

I have upload my app to App Store on Sep 5, 2014 after itunes redesign by chance. And I uploaded my app by xcode successfully, but the app status is always "waiting for upload" so far. 
The status should theoretically be "waiting for review", but it never changed and I have never received the notification email from App Store.

I'm not sure whether it is a bug of new ituens or any critical step I missed. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681089/waiting-for-upload-status-issue-in-new-itune-connect-site

Comment: that means u r not uploaded ur binary file , if u r did that u seen the message waiting for review

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all.

maddy's answer is correct. I just submit my app to review manually in "version" page of itunesconnect, the status was changed.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and I just uploaded the binary again. Third time it showed up.